# Linq Group by and inner join

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I would like to replace this SQL command :

```
string dotazBankUcty = @"SELECT 
     H.UCET, 
     SUM(H.KON_STAV_MD) AS KON_STAV_MD, 
     SUM(H.KON_STAV_DAL) AS KON_STAV_DAL , 
     SUM(H.KON_STAV_MD_MENA) AS KON_STAV_MD_MENA, 
     SUM(H.KON_STAV_DAL_MENA) AS KON_STAV_DAL_MENA, 
     MAX(UBUC.KOD_MENY) AS KOD_MENY 
     FROM UHLAVAKT H 
     inner join UBUC on H.UCET = UBUC.UCET GROUP BY H.UCET";
```

with a LINQ command. I tried this, but it returns a left join instead of an inner join, which I want.

```
var uhlavAktQuery = new XPQuery<UHLAVAKT>(CoreHelper.DataSession);

var ubucQuery = new XPQuery<UBUC>(CoreHelper.DataSession);

var resultBankyUcty = (from h in uhlavAktQuery
    join u in ubucQuery on h.CompoundKey1.UCET equals u.UCET
    group new { h, u } by new { h.CompoundKey1.UCET } into gUcty
                    select new
                    {
                    Ucet = gUcty.Key.UCET,
                    KON_STAV_MD = gUcty.Sum(k => k.h.KONSTAVMD),
                    KON_STAV_DAL = gUcty.Sum(k => k.h.KONSTAVDAL),
                    KON_STAV_MD_MENA = gUcty.Sum(k => k.h.KONSTAVMDMENA),
                    KON_STAV_DAL_MENA = gUcty.Sum(k => k.h.KONSTAVDALMENA),
                    KOD_MENY = gUcty.Max(k => k.u.KODMENY)
                    });
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: the `join` you used is **obviously** inner join, you should describe what you want to do first, how your query works for you.

Comment: This might help ... http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1883

Comment: I have SQL query and i would like to rewrite it by linq. This sql command only joins two table and on them do group by. Problem is in group by. When i use group by under one table, all is ok and linq commant returns the same result as sql command. But when i want to join two table and then group  by H.Ucet (for example) then it returns other result as my sql command. The result is the same as when using a Left Join, but i want default inner join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was struggling to get my head around joins with LINQ, I found the following article on CodeProject very informative and helpful:

[LINQ Extended Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488643/LinQ-Extended-Joins)

With the aid of examples including diagrams he explains what joins are and presents generic extension methods for IEnumerable which implement the various join queries.

Comment: INNER JOIN can not be used over Xpo layer, I have to use LEFT OUTER JOIN and WHERE != null